# Grouping strings from a set to a dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set, permutation

**Input:**

```
>>> foo = {("A", "B"), ("A", "G"), ("A", "H"),
...         ("B", "C"), ("B", "H"),
...         ("C", "D"),
...         ("D", "E"), ("D", "G"), ("D", "H"),
...         ("E", "F"), ("E", "G"), ("E", "H"),
...         ("F", "I"), ("F", "J"), ("F", "K"),
...         ("G", "H")}
```

I am trying to group my set like this, so far I have been unsuccessful, I managed to group them only like this.

**Actual output:**

```
>>> {k:set(x[1] for x in v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(sorted(foo), key=lambda x: x[0])}
{'B': {'C', 'H'}, 'E': {'H', 'G', 'F'}, 'D': {'E', 'G', 'H'}, 'A': {'B', 'G', 'H'}, 'C': {'D'}, 'G': {'H'}, 'F': {'I', 'K', 'J'}}
```

However, this is is my **desired output**:

```
foo1  = {"A": {"B", "G", "H"},
         "B": {"A", "H", "C"},
         "C": {"B", "D"},
         "D": {"C", "E", "G", "H"},
         "E": {"D", "F", "G", "H"},
         "F": {"E", "I", "J", "K"},
         "G": {"A", "D", "E", "H"},
         "H": {"A", "B", "D", "E", "G"},
         "I": {"F"},
         "J": {"F"},
         "K": {"F"}
         }
```

I was thinking with permutations or combinations? But I still don't have an idea how to do it.
Thanks in advance.
Edit: Added a picture of how the strings are related.

Comment: What do you want to determine how the strings are grouped? EDIT: wait, I think I see it, but please put this in the question too

Comment: Given that Python set and dict are by essence unordered, do you expect a particular order for your output ?

Comment: Your sorting dict comprehension does sort properly, but it doesn't print it to you in a way that you want? Edit: nvm, I see some errors in the one you got

Comment: If you're doing work with graphs, check out NetworkX.

Comment: I am not doing with graphs

Comment: Please do not deface your post

Comment: For the record, if your original `foo` is created as a `set` literal but the values were originally ordered as shown, you could just skip the `set` and initialize it as a `tuple` or `list`. If the data is already ordered, you don't need to resort it for use with `itertools.groupby`, which gets better performance than any other option (needing to sort means `O(n log n)` work, using a `defaultdict(set)` is theoretically `O(n)`, but has a much higher constant factor and worse worst case performance than the also `O(n)` `itertools.groupby` on already sorted data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP requested this to be done with a comprehension, so here's a gratuitous one liner:

(Please, please please don't do it this way)

```
python3
Python 3.5.2+ (default, Sep 22 2016, 12:18:14) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160927] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import itertools
>>> import pprint
>>> 
>>> foo = {("A", "B"), ("A", "G"), ("A", "H"),
...         ("B", "C"), ("B", "H"),
...         ("C", "D"),
...         ("D", "E"), ("D", "G"), ("D", "H"),
...         ("E", "F"), ("E", "G"), ("E", "H"),
...         ("F", "I"), ("F", "J"), ("F", "K"),
...         ("G", "H")}
>>> 
>>> foo1 = {k: {x[1] for x in v} for k, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(foo | {(a, b) for b, a in foo}), key=lambda x: x[0])}
>>> pprint.pprint(foo1)
{'A': {'H', 'B', 'G'},
 'B': {'C', 'H', 'A'},
 'C': {'D', 'B'},
 'D': {'C', 'E', 'H', 'G'},
 'E': {'D', 'H', 'F', 'G'},
 'F': {'K', 'J', 'E', 'I'},
 'G': {'D', 'E', 'H', 'A'},
 'H': {'D', 'E', 'B', 'G', 'A'},
 'I': {'F'},
 'J': {'F'},
 'K': {'F'}}
```

Comment: `{(k, v) for k in foo1 for v in foo1[k]}`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: What is that replacing? Whatever it's replacing, it would be mildly nicer to do it as `{(k, v) for k, vs in foo1.items() for v in vs}`; saves a redundant lookup for every key, but I'm not sure what the purpose of it is.

Comment: @ShadowRanger OP asked for a way to get their original list back from the dictionary, but then deleted their comment.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: Ah, that make sense. That set comprehension won't actually recover the original `set` though; the original `set` was deduplicated such that the first element of each pair was always less than the second element of each pair (so you'd see `A, B` but not `B, A`). If you want to preserve that invariant, you'd want: `{(k, v) for k, vs in foo1.items() for v in vs if k < v}`, to filter out the duplicate associations.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I realized that, but didn't notice how the original data was ordered. Good catch on the `<`

Answer (score 4):

Something like this ?

```
foo = {("A", "B"), ("A", "G"), ("A", "H"), ("B", "C"), ("B", "H"), ("C", "D"), ("D", "E"), ("D", "G"), ("D", "H"), ("E", "F"), ("E", "G"), ("E", "H"), ("F", "I"), ("F", "J"), ("F", "K"), ("G", "H")}

from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(set)

for key1, key2 in foo:
    result[key1].add(key2)
    result[key2].add(key1)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

Which, contrary to the other answers so far, produces the desired output, albeit unordered:

```
{'A': {'B', 'G', 'H'},
'B': {'A', 'C', 'H'},
'C': {'B', 'D'},
'D': {'G', 'C', 'H', 'E'},
'E': {'G', 'D', 'H', 'F'},
'F': {'I', 'J', 'K', 'E'},
'G': {'A', 'D', 'H', 'E'},
'H': {'B', 'A', 'G', 'D', 'E'},
'I': {'F'},
'J': {'F'},
'K': {'F'}}
```

Comment: @HappyUnicorn you can do it with a comprehension: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40639178/833093

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regular dictionary, but a `defaultdict` makes this a little easier.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d=defaultdict(set)
for key, value in foo:
    f[key].add(value)
```

With a regular dict:

```
d = {}
for key, value in foo:
    if key not in d:
        d[key]=set()
    d[key].add(value)
```

Comment: For the record, while it wastes time creating empty sets and discarding them, you could simplify the regular dict case from three `dict` lookups down to one by removing the membership testing and just doing: `for key, value in foo:`, `foo1.setdefault(key, set()).add(value)`, `foo1.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)`. Or to avoid the overhead of `set` calls, in Py 3.5 and higher, use the one-eyed monkey operator (named coined by me) to make an empty set via syntax instead of constructor calls: `foo1.setdefault(key, {*()}).add(value)`. :-)